# Can't use manual connection settings on tor?

Tags: php, http, proxy, tor, socks

I'm trying to use Burpsuite with my new operating system & Tor browser, and I can't seem to get it working, I go to "Preferences > Advanced > Network > Connection > settings" and I changed to Manual Proxy Configuration, HTTP Proxy to 127.0.0.1 (port 8080), then I selected Remote DNS. When I try to use this, I get the following error:

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to route your traffic through the Tor network and use BurpSuite's proxy, there's no point in using Tor browser and this won't work how you think.

You can't use multiple proxies in the browser like this.  Your browser traffic either goes through Tor's SOCKS proxy (default settings) or unencrypted through Burp.

Put simply, your settings won't make the requests go through Burp Suite for inspection or modification then out to Tor which is what I think you're going for.

If you want to see and manipulate browser requests in Burp suite while hitting your target through Tor, the settings need to be such that your browser proxies through Burp then from there out to Tor using firewall rules or telling Burp to use a SOCKS proxy for it's traffic (if it supports that).